# Background worker variable assignments in DoWork

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I am using a `BackgroundWorker` a bit differently than I was used to.

Usually, I use the BW to update some graphical control, and I perform all the required task in the `DoWork` method, return the result and do the assignments to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.

Here, I just wanted to assign the result of some computation (DB query) to some private variable `_myList` of the current Window.

I was very suprised to see that I was allowed to assign the list from the `DoWork` method, and I was really surprised.

I just wanted to know if it was normal or if it was not recommended for some reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will be allowed to assign to the variable as it doesn't have any checks guarding against cross-thread actions, the only things that do these checks are the UI elements.

As for if it is recommended, you are stepping into the realms of multi-threaded synchronisation.

Usually you lock access to a resource before attempting to use it, to guard against things like race conditions:

```
static object Locker = new object();

lock (Locker)
{
   // variable assignment in here.
}
```

If your usage is basic, as in, you set into it then at the end of the background worker chunk you read from it, then you will be safe to do this.  However, if other stuff attempts to write to it, or you have code that checks variable content before acting on it, then you start to get race conditions.

Answer (score 3):

I would always try to avoid accessing any kind of variables (not just UI controls) from the background workers DoWork event. It may seem to work most of the time but it is not 100% proof. If the variables are static then I do not have a problem with accessing them.

If I have more than a couple of variables the worker needs to work with then I would tend on creating a small class or struct to hold all variables then pass that to the DoWork event and return any updated values in the e.Result of the background worker. Then in the WorkerCompleted event I can update any local variables accordingly

Answer (score 2):

This is wanted, since variables are not protected against CrossThreading like UI Controls.

You have to be careful to not let two seperate threads access objects at the same, especially if it is a more complex data structure like List or Dictionary, which can lead to very strange results and exceptions.

To synchronice access to an object, you can use the [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) statement, if needed.

Value types like int, uint and so on should be no problem in theory.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1c9txz50.aspx) page on MSDN provides a nice starting point for threading.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly normal and ok. You are just not allowed to access controls from a different thread than the one that created them. For all other variables, there is no such restriction.
However, you need to be careful about other problems related to threading: If you have two threads that access the same variable, you might run into problems if the access is not synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with synchronizing data "offline" so to speak if you decide that it is reasonable for the user to still be able to use the UI while this process is happening.

I have done this a lot. Particularly when developing mobile applications.